# Update table cell content when dropdown menu is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html table and I have added a dropdown menu to all of the `td` elements in one of the columns using javascript.  I want to code it so that when the user selects and option from the dropdown menu, it updates the value of another cell in that row.  The dropdown menu works fine, but I am having trouble figuring out how to get it to update the corresponding `CONFIRMATION` cell.

The table looks like this:
[image: my html table]

The JS code I've come up with so far looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var table = document.getElementById("req_table");
  var cells = table.getElementsByTagName('th');

  $(function(){
    $("tr").each(function(){
      //this is where I create/add the dropdown menu to the table//
      var dropdown_str = "<div class='dropdown'><button id='dLabel' type='button' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'>Request Action<span class='caret'></span></button><ul aria-labelledby='drop4' class='dropdown-menu' id='menu1'><li class='Confirm'><a href='#'>Confirm</a></li><li class='Reject'><a href='#'>Reject</a></li></ul></div>";
      $(this).find("td:eq(2)").append(dropdown_str);
    });
  });
  //this is where I tried to update the CONFIRMATION cell//
  $('.Confirm').on('click',function(){
    $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text = "CONFIRM";
  });
});
```

The html table is created from a pandas dataframe using `DataFrame.to_html()`.

Can anyone tell me how to update the `CONFIRMATION` cell when the user selects one of the options from the drop down menu?

Comment: Paste the generated HTML code for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the parent row with `.parents("tr").first()` and update the content with `.html()`

```
$('body').on('click',".Confirm",function(){
    $(this).parents("tr").first().find("td:eq(1)").html("CONFIRM");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `$(this).find` inside the `click` event, but `this` refers to the `li` clicked there.

So, you should get the closest `tr` parent to find the `td` you want:

```
$('.Confirm').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(1)").text("CONFIRM");
});
```

You were using the `text` method as it was a property, but it is a function, so I've fixed that too.